# Is there any nuget package available for c# Naming Convention in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, naming-conventions, nuget-package

I am new to c# programming, i want to know is there any nuget package available in Visual Studio c# for naming conventions or any other external tool or free dll,which programmers normally use while do coding.

Thanks

Comment: This one might be useful: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: Check out [StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/)  you can even integrate it with Resharper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say take a look at StyleCop. [StyleCop on Github](https://github.com/StyleCop)

It can be installed as a [Visual Studio Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5441d959-387f-4cb2-a8c0-9998dd1fa49f) or as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.MSBuild) into your project which allows you to use it without installing anything into your system.

Another helpful bit of software that can help enforce style and name conventions (in addition to a lot of other helpful tools) is [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), although you'll need to pay for a license for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try FxCop, you can set custom rules to check for variable name:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476.aspx

Comment: FxCop isn't really meant for catching naming conventions.  You may be thinking of StyleCop